# How to hardcode mongoexport field data

Tags: mongodb, field, mongoexport

My MongoExport will pull three fields
--fields firstname,lastname,email,city

output:

```
firstname,lastname,email,city
"Fn1","Ln1","abc@abc.com","chicago"
"Fn2","Ln2","xyz@xyz.com","atlanta"
```

I want emails to be hidden so I need a hardcoded value 'EMAIL' instead of the actual email.

```
"Fn1","Ln1","EMAIL","chicago"
"Fn2","Ln2","EMAIL","atlanta"
```

Can this be done in mongo export?

Comment: No. You can alter which fields are exported, but you can't put in a dummy value for a field.